# remove file command not working on spaces name

Tags: python, bash

my file name is

```
file_name = '19-00165_my-test - Copy (7)_Basic_sample_data'
```

my function is like

```
call("rm -rf /tmp/" + file_name + '.csv', shell=True)
```

but getting this error

**/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('**

Comment: `file_name` cannot use this quote `. it needs to use this one '

Comment: You need to escape the spaces with a backslash. Try `file_name.replace(' ', '\ ')`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki that's bcz some formating of stackoverflow , fixed nnow

Comment: What is *call()* ?

Comment: `call(["rm", "-rf", "/tmp/" + file_name + ".csv"])`

Answer (score 1):

My response always is: Don't use space in files.

But if you *really* want this, than you should place the files in quotes as such:

```py
call("rm -f '/tmp/{0}.csv'".format(file_name), shell=True)
```

Comment: p.s. you don't need `-r`, because you're removing a file instead of a directory.

Comment: Absolutely right, with two caveats: (1) if you are forming shell commands then there are more characters to worry about than just spaces, and (2) putting the name inside single quotes (`'`) that are seen by the shell takes care of all of them ***except*** the single-quote character itself.

Comment: You should also escape single quotes: ``.replace("'", "'\\''")``.

Comment: Not exactly, @Cubix48. The shell does not recognize any escaping inside single-quoted strings, not even of single quotes.  For full generality, one needs a different underlying approach, such as escaping every special character individually instead of using a single-quoted string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes that's why I replace each ``'`` with ``'\''``. I close the quoted string with ``'``, add ``\'``, and then open a new single quoted string with ``'``. However, I completely agree that it is better to escape each character individually.

Comment: This fails if the file name includes a `'`. You could just `call` with a list and without `shell=True` to make your life 10 times easier.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid having problems with unescaped characters, one way is to use the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) module:

You can use the `quote()` function to escape the string, it returns a shell-escaped version of the string:

```py
import shlex

file_name = "19-00165_my-test - Copy (7)_Basic_sample_'data"

call(f"rm -f /tmp/{shlex.quote(file_name)}.csv", shell=True)
# rm -rf /tmp/'19-00165_my-test - Copy (7)_Basic_sample_'"'"'data'.csv
```

You can also use `join()`:

```py
import shlex

file_name = "19-00165_my-test - Copy (7)_Basic_sample_'data"

call(shlex.join(["rm", "-f", f"/tmp/{file_name}.csv"]), shell=True)
# rm -f '/tmp/19-00165_my-test - Copy (7)_Basic_sample_'"'"'data.csv'
```

---

**Note:** This answer is only valid if `shell=True` is required to make the command work. Otherwise the answer of @Gordon Davisson is way easier.

Comment: Or just `call` with a list and without `shell=True` to make your life 10 times easier...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `shell=True`? That means the command will be passed to a shell for parsing, which is what's causing all the trouble. With `shell=False`, you pass a list consisting of the commands followed by its arguments, each as a separate list element (rather than all mashed together as a single string). Since the filename never goes through shell parsing, it can't get mis-parsed.

```
call(["rm", "-rf", "/tmp/" + file_name + '.csv'], shell=False)
```